# Таймер обратного отчета jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте! Нужен таймер обратного отчета, по истечению которого перебрасывает на index.html. Таймер появляется спустя 30 секунд неактивности пользователя, если пользователь не успевает кликнуть - перебрасывает на главную страницу. Если успевает - таймер закрывается.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Полный фрагмент кода для этой задачи.
Для более наглядной демонстрации я сделал интервал простоя 3 секунды, а не 30. А обратный отчёт изменил с 60 до 6 секунд.

```js
$(function() {
  var idleTimeout;
  var countdownTimeout;
  
  resetTimer();
  
  $(document).on("mousemove keydown scroll", function() {
    // если модальное окно спрятано, то сбрасываем таймер при активности
    if (!$(".timer-popup").is(":visible")) {
      resetTimer();
    }
  });
  
  $(".timer-popup__button").click(function() {
    resetTimer();
    clearTimeout(countdownTimeout);
  });
  
  function showTimer() {
   $(".timer-popup").css("display", "inline-flex");
    $(".timer-popup__time").text("6");
    
    var redirect = function() { 
      /* Укажите url вашей страницы  */
      window.location = "http://stackoverflow.com"; 
    };
    
    showSeconds(redirect);
  }
  
  function resetTimer() {
    $(".timer-popup").css("display", "none");
    clearTimeout(idleTimeout);
    idleTimeout = setTimeout(showTimer, 3000);
  }
  
  function showSeconds(callback) {
    countdownTimeout = setTimeout(function() {
     var seconds = parseInt($(".timer-popup__time").text());
      
      if (seconds === 0) {
        callback();
        return false;
      }
      
     $(".timer-popup__time").text((--seconds).toString());
      showSeconds(callback);
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

```css
* {
  /* Просто для красоты установил шрифт */
  font-family: Arial;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.timer-popup {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  
  /* Прячем диалог */
  /* Когда будем показывать установим inline-flex */
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* Отцентрировать содержимое по горизонтали */
  align-items: center;
  
  position: absolute;
  /* Отцентрировать по горинтали и вертикали */
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.timer-popup__caption {
  font-size: 20px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.timer-popup__time {
  margin-top: 5px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

.timer-popup__button {
  outline: 0;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="timer-popup">
  <span сlass="timer-popup__caption">Press OK to Continue</span>
  <span class="timer-popup__time">6</span>
  <button class="timer-popup__button">
    OK
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: У вас выглядит более чисто

Comment: Вадим, мне кажется что за помощь в разработке этого небольшого проекта можно взять в долю)) Спасибо вам большое за ответы и за всю помощь в целом. Я, конечно же, понимаю, что очень не красиво задавать такие вопросы, которые последнее время я тут задаю, но взял проект, который довольно тяжелый оказался. Много уроков из этого вынес и отправил на проверку уже

Comment: Жаль, нельзя 2 ответа принять правильным :)

Comment: @Atomrr Да я бы не сказал так. Какой вам кажется полезней, тот и принимайте. Крайне редко, когда ответы бывают *одинаково* полезны.

Comment: Ваш ответ более информативный, как для, довольно таки, зеленого в js  меня, и ваш ответ я бы взял на дальнейшее вооружение в виде гиста :) А вообще, нужно прям сегодня начать основательно изучать js

Comment: @Atomrr Если он более информативный, так и выбирайте его как принятый. Это ваше право *вне зависимости от уровня* знаний в области знаний вопроса выбирать *любой* ответ, который решил вашу проблему. Это и есть предназначение "принятого ответа".

Comment: Да, принял ваш. Отправил уже на проверку с фрагментом кода Yuri, но для себя оставлю ваш ответ. Спасибо вам еще раз :)

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(function() {
  var tim = function() {setTimeout(function() {
    var t = 60;
    $('.timer .time').text(t);
    $('.timer').css({display: 'block'});
    var int = setInterval(function() {
      t--;
      if(t == -1){
        clearInterval(int);
        location.href = 'index.html';
      }else{
        $('.timer .time').text(t);
      }
    }, 1000);
    $('button').click(function() {
      clearInterval(int);
      $('.timer').css({display: 'none'});
      tim();
    });
  }, 30000)};
  tim();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="timer" style="display:none">
  <span class="time"></span>
  <button>Кликни</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ. Только открывается в новой вкладке, а можно в этой же, в которой таймер запущен?

Comment: И, если можно, то после клика - он закрывается и больше не появляется. Нужно что бы он запустился еще раз спустя какое то время. Буду очень благодарен

Comment: @Atomrr, держите. И мой совет: не задавайте таких вопросов. Никто больше вместо вас писать код не будет. Это не форум. Здесь люди помогают исправлять ошибки, а не писать код

Comment: Спасибо большое. Да, я это понял и ужас как неудобно это просить здесь. Проект взял, который не потянул, как оказалось.

Comment: @Atomrr Yuri, конечно, прав, но мне очень понравился ваш вопрос и я получил много удовольствия от разработки решения для этой задачи:)